# REST API Best Practices: Where should data be passed in POST requests? Parameters, Endpoint, Body?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, restful-url, flask-restful

I know this is a fairly general question, but I've searched around and can't really find any best practices or guidelines about API design specifically for accepting data in `POST`/`PUT` requests.

So, what are the best practices to follow when designing your API and are there any rules or guidelines that you follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when data is POSTed to a HTTP server, the relevant data related to what you're posting will be in the body.

I say generally because there are exceptions.

This is even more so the case with `PUT`, the data really should be in the body. If there is no body in a `PUT` request, the meaning of the request is: "please replace this resource with a 0-byte resource".

Comment: Okay thanks! This is what I've been doing but then I came across an article that said APIs should be as intuitive as possible and that if the data is fairly simple then passing it as params is preferred over the body.

Comment: @Zach I think most people would disagree with that article :) Intuitive to me is also the 'least amount of surprise', and most people will pass data in a body, and meta-data in headers.